# clear doesn't work in ipython after doing a reset

Tags: python, ipython, nameerror

In `IPython`, if I do a `clear` in the shell, it clears the shell all right, and if I do a `reset`, then it resets all the shell variables.

However, if I do a `clear` after I have done a `reset`, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'clear' is not defined
```

Why is this happening so?

I am using `ipython v1.2.1`

PS: If this is off-topic, let me know, I will remove the question